# How can I catch timeout exception in laravel queue

Tags: laravel, exception, queue

I have Laravel database driver queue and supervisord in docker.

I know that queue can down with exception:

> The process "'/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' queue:work '' --once --queue='default' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException(code: 0): The process \"'/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' queue:work '' --once --queue='default' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3\" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds. at /app/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:1236)

How can I catch exception in my code when I push my queue in controller, not giving to down all server with Getaway timeout

```
Queue::pushOn('default', new Adservice());


[program:laravel-worker]
command=php /app/artisan queue:listen database --queue=default --tries=1 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
priority=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/app/storage/logs/supervisor.log
```

//Adservice

```
public function handle(){ 
$this->timeout=3;
$time_start = microtime(true);
try{
 usleep(100);
 $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    dump($time);//13
 }catch(\Exception $e){
          Log::error('GetCsvFromSftp.php: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").$e);
          throw $e; // rethrow to make job fail
        }

}
```

Also I can not kill the job by setting timeout inside the job variable
pcntl support in php.ini    enabled

Comment: What code are you running within your `AdService`?

Comment: The problem and the question is not depends on Adservice It can be any Job , my question is how to catch exception and not lay down the server when timeout error can come